# REST Client InboundJaxrsResponse Status 500 , when attempting to POST

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, jaxb2

Issue 1. I'm getting a Http Status 500, when I'm setting the Todo object with the Todo constructor. It works fine for an existing value set in the TodoDao. What is that I'm missing here ?( please find the code and stack trace below ) :

Issue 2. I'm attempting to set and the form param as follows, but i'm unable to resolve the  following  compilation error :

```
> The method post(Entity<?>, Class<T>) in the type SyncInvoker is not
> applicable for the arguments (Class<Form>, Form)
```

Code snippet setting the form :

```
Form form = new Form();
                    form.param("id","45");
                    form.param("summary","Summary for id 45");
                    response =         target.path("rest").path("todos").path(todo.getId()).request()
                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(Form.class,form);
```

**Stacktrace :**
`

```
Response Code is : 500
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><todoes><todo><description>Rest todo Description 2 </description><id>2</id><summary>Summary 2 - REST</summary></todo><todo><description>Rest todo Description 1</description><id>1</id><summary>Summary 1 - REST</summary></todo><todo><id>45</id><summary>Summary for id 45</summary></todo></todoes>

Post response200
```

`

**TodosResourceClient.java**

```
package com.dcr.jersey.client;



import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;


import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo; 

public class TodosResourceClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI());

        Todo todo = new Todo("38","38 - Summary ReEntred");

        target.path("rest").path("todos").request().post(Entity.json(todo));

        Response response = target.path("rest").path("todos").path(todo.getId()).request()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Response.class);

        System.out.println("\n POST Response Code is : "+ response.getStatus());



       System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todos").path(todo.getId()).request()
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(Response.class)
                        .toString()+"\n");

    System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todos").request()
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class)+"\n");

    System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todos").request()
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class)+"\n");

    System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todos/34").request()
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class)+"\n");


                //target.path("rest").path("todos/38").request().delete();

                System.out.println(target.path("rest").path("todos").request()
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class)+"\n");

                Form form = new Form();
                form.param("id","45");
                form.param("summary","Summary for id 45");
                response = target.path("rest").path("todos").request().post(Entity.form(form));

                System.out.println("\nPost by FORM response code is "+ response.getStatus()+"\n");

                response = target.path("rest").path("todos/45").request().delete();// deletes a request

                System.out.println("\nDelete by FORM response code is "+ response.getStatus()+"\n");


    }
    private static URI getBaseURI() {

        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/com.dcr.jersey.first").build();

      }

}
```

**Todo.java**

```
package com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement

public class Todo {

    private String id;
    private String summary;
    private String description;
    public Todo(){}
    public Todo(String id,String summary){
        this.id=id;
        this.summary=summary;

    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

**create_todo.htm:**  ( this is saved under Deployed Resources>webapp folder )

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Form to create a new resource</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

  <style>
    tab { padding-left: 4em; }
    </style>
 </head>
<body>

<form id= "myForm" action="../com.dcr.jersey.first/rest/todos" >

  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input name="id" />
  <br/>
  <label for="summary">Summary</label>
  <input name="summary" />
  <br/>
  Description:
  <TEXTAREA NAME="description" COLS=40 ROWS=6></TEXTAREA>
  <br/> 
  <button type="button" value="Submit">Submit</button>  <tab> <button type="button" value="Delete">Delete</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $("button.Submit").click(function(){
            $("#myForm").attr("method", "POST");
            $("#myForm").attr("action", "../com.dcr.jersey.first/rest/todos");
        });

        $("button.Delete").click(function(){
            $("#myForm").attr("method", "DELETE");
        });
  </script>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**TodosResource.java**

```
package com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.resources;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.dao.TodoDao;
import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo;
//Will map the resource to the URL todos
@Path("/todos")
public class TodosResource {

    // Allows to insert contextual objects into the class,
      // e.g. ServletContext, Request, Response, UriInfo
      @Context
      UriInfo uriInfo;
      @Context
      Request request;
      @Context
      Todo todo;
    // Return the list of todos to the user in the browser
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public List<Todo> getTodosBrowser() {
        List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        todos.addAll(TodoDao.instance.getModel().values());
        return todos;
      }
    // Return the list of todos for applications
      @GET
      @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
      public List<Todo> getTodos() {
        List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        todos.addAll(TodoDao.instance.getModel().values());
        return todos;
      }
    // retuns the number of todos
      // Use http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/todos/count
      // to get the total number of records
      @GET
      @Path("count")
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String getCount() {
        int count = TodoDao.instance.getModel().size();
        return String.valueOf(count);
      }

      @POST
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      public void newTodo(@FormParam("id") String id,
          @FormParam("summary") String summary,
          @FormParam("description") String description,
          @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
        Todo todo = new Todo(id, summary);
        if (description != null) {
          todo.setDescription(description);
        }
        TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(id, todo);
        servletResponse.sendRedirect("../Created_PopUp.html");
      }  

      @POST
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

      public void newTodoXMLJSON(Todo todo) throws IOException {
        this.todo=todo;
        TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(todo.getId(), todo);
      }  

      @DELETE
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      public void delTodo(@FormParam("id") String id,
          @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
          Todo c = TodoDao.instance.getModel().remove(id);
            if(c==null)
              throw new RuntimeException("Delete: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
            else servletResponse.sendRedirect("../create_todo.html");
      }  

      @Path("{todo}")
      public TodoResource getTodo(@PathParam("todo") String id) {
            return new TodoResource(uriInfo, request, id);
      }
}
```

**TodoDao.java**

```
package com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.dao;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo;


public enum TodoDao {
    instance;
    private Map<String,Todo> contentProvider = new HashMap<String, Todo>();
    private TodoDao(){
        Todo todo = new Todo("1","Summary 1 - REST");
        todo.setDescription("Rest todo Description 1");
        contentProvider.put("1",todo);
        todo = new Todo("2","Summary 2 - REST");
        todo.setDescription("Rest todo Description 2 ");
        contentProvider.put("2", todo);
    }
    public Map<String,Todo> getModel(){
        return contentProvider;
    }
}
```

**TodoResource.java**

```
package com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.resources;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
//import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
//import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo;
import com.dcr.jersey.jaxb.dao.TodoDao;



public class TodoResource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;
    String id;

    public TodoResource(UriInfo uriInfo, Request request, String id) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        this.request = request;
        this.id = id;
      }

    //Application Integration     
      @GET
      @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
      public Todo getTodo() {
        Todo todo = TodoDao.instance.getModel().get(id);
        if(todo==null)
          throw new RuntimeException("Get: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
        return todo;
      }

    // for the browser
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
      public Todo getTodoHTML() {
        Todo todo = TodoDao.instance.getModel().get(id);
        if(todo==null)
          throw new RuntimeException("Get: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
        return todo;
      }
      @PUT
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
      public Response putTodo(JAXBElement<Todo> todo) {
        Todo c = todo.getValue();
        return putAndGetResponse(c);
      }

      @DELETE
      public void deleteTodo() {
        Todo c = TodoDao.instance.getModel().remove(id);
        if(c==null)
          throw new RuntimeException("Delete: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
      }

      private Response putAndGetResponse(Todo todo) {
            Response res;
            if(TodoDao.instance.getModel().containsKey(todo.getId())) {
              res = Response.noContent().build();
            } else {
              res = Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()).build();
            }
            TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(todo.getId(), todo);
            return res;
          }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

You're getting Server errors, because you are throwing a `RuntimException`, when the looked up `Todo` is null. It will always be null, because you are looking it up with the id `34`, which doesn't exist. You can see that all the request where you use the id in the URL are the ones failing.

You might want to throw something more appropriate, that will get mapped to a response, like `NotFoundException`, which will get mapped to a 404 response

**Issue 2:**

```
Response response = target.path("rest").path("todos").path(todo.getId())
                          .request()
                          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                          .post(Form.class,form)
```

Let's break down what's wrong.

1. `.path(todo.getId())`. By the looks of it, you are trying to post to `newTodo`. That method doesn't have a template for and id. Get rid of that completely.
2. `.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`. The request will get redirected to an HTML page, so the response will not be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So you can completely get rid of that. You don't need to explicitly set the header in this case.
3. `.post(Form.class,form)`. Take a look at the [different `post` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post%28javax.ws.rs.client.Entity%29)

   - `Response post(Entity<?> entity)`
   - `<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, Class<T> responseType)`
   - `<T> T post(Entity<?> entity, GenericType<T> responseType)`

   You want to receive back a `Response`, so you will use the first one. It requires only an [`Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html). If you look at some of the API methods, you will see a static [`form(Form)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#form%28javax.ws.rs.core.Form%29) method.

   > Create an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" form entity.

   This is what you want to use `Entity.form(form)`

So your complete request can look like

```
Form form = new Form();
form.param("id", "45");
form.param("summary", "Summary for id 45");
Response response = client.target(url).request().post(Entity.form(form));
String html = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(html);
```

Comment: many thanks for answering, for Issue 1, I added the TodoDao code. and regarding your "Aside", can you please give me an issutration of what you mean by "What you should be doing, is looking up the Todo by the id, and sending that back as the response."

Comment: I didn't see the `TodoResource`. I thought the Sub-Resource locator was calling the `TodosResource`

Comment: See the updated first part. It is because you are using an id that doesn't exist, and you are explicitly throwing a RuntimeException, with no ExceptionMapper to handle it. So the Exception bubbles up to the container level, which sends out a 500

Comment: Use the id `1` in the path (replacing 34) and it should work. I've tested it and it works fine

Comment: Ok, the 500(`TodosResourceClient.java`) is for : ` Response response = target.path("rest").path("todos").path(todo.getId()).request()
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Response.class);` . This is the constructor call `Todo todo = new Todo("34","Summary Entred"); ` does not insert the kv ( "34","Summary Entred" )

Comment: I already know what the errors are for. I told you. It's for every request where you are adding the ID to the path, either with `path(todo.getid())` or `path("todos/34")`. And I said the reason is that there _is_ no todo with id `34` in your dao. Use `1` and you will see it work

Comment: You don't do anything with the `Todo` you create. It does not get sent with the request. All you're requests are GET requests. It would be the same as not creating the `Todo` and simple using `path("34")` for all your request. The only request that sends a POST with data, is the one where you are trying to send the `Form`

Comment: yes, it works for '1' and i'm aware of it. How should I code to work for '34', is it something like this that should go after the constructor call `target.path("rest").path("todos").request().post(what should go here??);`

Comment: `Entity.json(todo)`, or `Entity.xml(todo)`, but you need to method that `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, ..._XML)` and accept a `Todo` method param

Comment: Or you can send the `Form` first. You already have a method to handle that

Comment: Ok thanks , got it I will try to include the `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, ..._XML)` in the current POST method (`newTodo`) and then I guess it should work !

Comment: No it wont work. That method is meant for a different format, that is not compatible with `Todo`. You need a separate method to handle xml and json

Comment: @peeskillet-  Yeah, you right it did not work, I updated the code for TodosResourceClient.java , but the code snippet for issue 2 is fixed. Will include a separate method to handle xml and json ( issue 1 ).

Comment: It works ! created a new method to handle xml and json. Many thanks for being helpful !

Comment: -I'm unable to POST and DELETE from create_todo.html file . the  I updated the source files in my orginal post.  Not sure what's wrong with create_todo.html, Any idea ? the TodosResourceClient.java works fine for POST and DELETE methods.

Answer (score 0):

**fix for Issue 1** : As suggested by @peeskillet, a new POST method that consumes MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON has been coded. This code has been updated in TodosResource.java service :

```
@POST
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})

  public void newTodoXMLJSON(Todo todo) throws IOException {
    this.todo=todo;
    TodoDao.instance.getModel().put(todo.getId(), todo);
  }
```

The call for this `newTodoXMLJSON()` method is from the `TodosResourceClient.java` which has been updated with these extra lines of code:

```
Todo todo = new Todo("34","34 - Summary Entered");
target.path("rest").path("todos").request().post(Entity.json(todo));
Response response = target.path("rest").path("todos").path(todo.getId()).request()
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Response.class);     
System.out.println("\n Response Code is : "+ response.getStatus());
```

**fix for Issue 2** : as suggested by @peeskilet

```
Form form = new Form();
form.param("id","45");
form.param("summary","Summary for id 45");
response =target.path("rest").path("todos").request().post(Entity.form(form));    
System.out.println("\nPost response"+ response.getStatus());
```